# Is this XML file, from PDF XFDF submission corrupt?

Tags: php, xml, pdf

It is sent from a PDF form as XFDF data and written to an .XML file using this PHP:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.fdf");
$fdf = file_get_contents("php://input");
$log = fopen("submission.xml","w");
fwrite($log, $fdf, strlen($fdf));
fclose($log);
```

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHj8L.png) of the XML file when opened in Notepad++

I ask, as I'm struggling to parse it using SimpleXML.

This:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("submission.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

Gives:

> `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [fields] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [field] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => button ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => email ) [value] => 007@mi5.co.uk ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => name ) [value] => James Bond ) ) ) [ids] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [original] => B59EEF3B5D6AC74984507B8EB01D7601 [modified] => 83AF2574691D8144BAF155B94CEE1562 ) ) )`

Comment: it's weirdly formatted, but doesn't LOOK corrupt... xml corruption is EASY to test for. just load it into an xml parser. if it's corrupt, the parser will barf.

Comment: well, obviously simplexml was able to parse it.